# Index Error: List Index out of range, when overwriting data inside a csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

In the code below, I pass the path of my csv file, the topic that the user played for the quiz, the username of the user, the score obtained by the user in the quiz they played, and the difficulty the user played the quiz on into my "QuizCSV" class.

In my "CSV" class, I pass the path of another csv file which contains the questions and answers for the quiz that the user chooses to play.

The program is meant to take the user's score from the quiz and store the score in a csv file named "Scores", but most importantly, the program has to overwrite any previous score the user got on the quiz, with the new score the user just got which is where my program goes wrong and gives me an INDEX ERROR.

This is my code(sorry for some unindented code for python):

```
class QuizCSV: #Now Functional through 'os' and 'sys' module

def __init__(self, path, topic, user, score, difficulty): 
    self.path = path
    self.topic = topic
    self.user = user
    self.score = score
    self.difficulty = difficulty

def writeScore(self):
    f = open(self.path, "r")
    for line in f:
        data = line.split(",")
        write_f = open("ScoresUpdated.csv", "a")
        if data[0] == self.user:
            if self.topic == "SCIENCE":
                if self.difficulty == "Easy":
                    write_f.write(data[0] + ',' + self.score + ',' + data[2] + ',' + data[3] + ',' + data[4] + ',' + data[5] + ',' + data[6]+"\n")
                if self.difficulty == "Medium":
                    write_f.write(data[0] + ',' + data[1] + ',' + self.score + ',' + data[3] + ',' + data[4] + ',' + data[5] + ',' + data[6]+"\n")
                if self.difficulty == "Hard":
                    write_f.write(data[0] + ',' + data[1] + ',' + data[2] + ',' + self.score + ',' + data[4] + ',' + data[5] + ',' + data[6]+"\n")
            elif self.topic == "COMPUTING":
                if self.difficulty == "Easy":
                    write_f.write(data[0] + ',' + data[1] + ',' + data[2] + ',' + data[3] + ',' + self.score + ',' + data[5] + ',' + data[6]+"\n")
                if self.difficulty == "Medium":
                    write_f.write(data[0] + ',' + data[1] + ',' + data[2] + ',' + data[3] + ',' + data[4] + ',' + self.score + ',' + data[6]+"\n")
                if self.difficulty == "Hard":
                    write_f.write(data[0] + ',' + data[1] + ',' + data[2] + ',' + data[3] + ',' + data[4] + ',' + data[5] + ',' + self.score+"\n")
        else:
            write_f.write(data[0] + ',' + data[1] + ',' + data[2] + ',' + data[3] + ',' + data[4] + ',' + data[5] + ',' + data[6])
        write_f.close()
    f.close()
    os.remove("Scores.csv")
    os.rename("ScoresUpdated.csv","Scores.csv")

class CSV:

    def __init__(self, path):
         self.path = path # raw string path; i.e. using r"/path/to/file"

    def write(self, data):  # list of strings ['Username', 'Password']
        with open(self.path, 'a') as w:
        w.seek(0, 2)
        w.writelines("\r")
        w.writelines((',').join(data))

    def Easy(self):
        correct = 0
        for x in range(5):
            with open(self.path, 'r') as r:
               reader = csv.reader(r, delimiter=',')
               for line in reader:
                   if "Question {}".format(x + 1)  == line[0]:
                   print(line[1])
                   answersCSV = [line[3], line[4], line[5]]
                   RandomAnswer = random.choice(answersCSV)
                   UserAnswers = [line[6], RandomAnswer]
                   shuffle(UserAnswers)
                   print ("A: {}".format(UserAnswers[0]))
                   print ("B: {}".format(UserAnswers[1]))

                   while True:
                       Question = input("Enter one of the answers above: ").lower()
                       if Question == UserAnswers[0]:
                           if UserAnswers[0] == line[6]:
                               print ("correct answer")
                               correct += 1
                           elif UserAnswers[0] != line[6]:
                               print ("incorrect answer")
                           break
                       elif Question == UserAnswers[1]:
                           if UserAnswers[1] == line[6]:
                               print ("correct answer")
                               correct += 1
                           elif UserAnswers[1] != line[6]:
                               print ("incorrect answer")
                           break
                       else:
                           print ("Please enter one of the answers above")


    print ("you got a score of {}".format(str(correct)))
    if self.path == "Science.csv":
        UserScore = QuizCSV("Scores.csv", "SCIENCE", userQ, str(correct), "Easy")
        UserScore.writeScore()
    if self.path == "Computing.csv":
        UserScore = QuizCSV("Scores.csv", "COMPUTING", userQ, str(correct), "Easy")
        UserScore.writeScore()

def Medium(self):
    correct = 0
    for x in range(5):
        with open(self.path, 'r') as r:
            reader = csv.reader(r, delimiter=',')
            for line in reader:
                if "Question {}".format(x + 1) == line[0]:
                    print(line[1])
                    answersCSV = [line[3], line[4], line[5]]
                    RandomAnswer = random.choice(answersCSV)
                    while True:
                        RandomAnswer2 = random.choice(answersCSV)
                        if RandomAnswer2 == RandomAnswer:
                            RandomAnswer2 = random.choice(answersCSV)
                        else:
                            break
                    UserAnswers = [line[6], RandomAnswer, RandomAnswer2]
                    shuffle(UserAnswers)
                    print("A: {}".format(UserAnswers[0]))
                    print("B: {}".format(UserAnswers[1]))
                    print ("C: {}".format(UserAnswers[2]))

                    while True:
                        Question = input("Enter one of the answers above: ").lower()
                        if Question == UserAnswers[0]:
                            if UserAnswers[0] == line[6]:
                                print("correct answer")
                                correct += 1
                            elif UserAnswers[0] != line[6]:
                                print("incorrect answer")
                            break
                        elif Question == UserAnswers[1]:
                            if UserAnswers[1] == line[6]:
                                print("correct answer")
                                correct += 1
                            elif UserAnswers[1] != line[6]:
                                print("incorrect answer")
                            break
                        elif Question == UserAnswers[2]:
                            if UserAnswers[2] == line[6]:
                                print ("correct answer")
                                correct += 1
                            elif UserAnswers[2] != line[6]:
                                print ("incorrect answer")
                            break
                        else:
                            print("Please enter one of the answers above")

    print("you got a score of {}".format(correct))
    if self.path == "Science.csv":
        UserScore = QuizCSV("Scores.csv", "SCIENCE", userQ, str(correct), "Medium")
        UserScore.writeScore()
    if self.path == "Computing.csv":
        UserScore = QuizCSV("Scores.csv", "COMPUTING", userQ, str(correct), "Medium")
        UserScore.writeScore()

def Hard(self):
    correct = 0
    for x in range(5):
        with open(self.path, 'r') as r:
            reader = csv.reader(r, delimiter=',')
            for line in reader:
                if "Question {}".format(x + 1) == line[0]:
                    print(line[1])
                    UserAnswers = [line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6]]
                    shuffle(UserAnswers)
                    print("A: {}".format(UserAnswers[0]))
                    print("B: {}".format(UserAnswers[1]))
                    print("C: {}".format(UserAnswers[2]))
                    print("D: {}".format(UserAnswers[3]))

                    while True:
                        Question = input("Enter one of the answers above: ").lower()
                        if Question == UserAnswers[0]:
                            if UserAnswers[0] == line[6]:
                                print("correct answer")
                                correct += 1
                            elif UserAnswers[0] != line[6]:
                                print("incorrect answer")
                            break
                        elif Question == UserAnswers[1]:
                            if UserAnswers[1] == line[6]:
                                print("correct answer")
                                correct += 1
                            elif UserAnswers[1] != line[6]:
                                print("incorrect answer")
                            break
                        elif Question == UserAnswers[2]:
                            if UserAnswers[2] == line[6]:
                                print("correct answer")
                                correct += 1
                            elif UserAnswers[2] != line[6]:
                                print("incorrect answer")
                            break
                        else:
                           print("Please enter one of the answers above")

    print("you got a score of {}".format(correct))
    if self.path == "Science.csv":
        UserScore = QuizCSV("Scores.csv", "SCIENCE", userQ, str(correct), "Hard")
        UserScore.writeScore()
    if self.path == "Computing.csv":
        UserScore = QuizCSV("Scores.csv", "COMPUTING", userQ, str(correct), "Hard")
        UserScore.writeScore()
```

Here's my csv file:

```
Username | Sci Easy | Sci Medium | Sci Hard | Comp Easy | Comp Medium | Comp Hard |   
SID16    |     5    |            |          |           |             |
```

When all the cells in the file for 'SID16' is empty, then the program stores the user's score in the appropriate cell. But, if the user plays the same quiz, the program does not overwrite the '5' mark and gives me a "INDEX ERROR" where the "list index" is out of range. I don't understand why my program is unable to overwrite the already written data with the user's new score, for example, overwriting 5 to 2.
How can I correct the index error, and why is it occurring? Thank you.

Comment: An `IndexError` means you are trying to access an element of a list that doesn't exist. For example, `[1, 2, 3][42]` is going to be an `IndexError` because we are trying to access the 42nd element in a 3 element list. However we can't help you with where the error is found without knowing where in your code the error occurs. Can you produce a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the behavior you're getting here, instead of your full program?

Comment: It's occurring in

Comment: write_f.write(...) where ... is all the cells in my csv file

Comment: write_f.write(data[0] + ',' + data[1] + ',' + data[2]... and so on till data[6])